# How can i take section as a button and clicking that button should display no of rows for that section?

Tags: iphone

For Ex:I have 5 Section each section should be displayed as Button where it also have button title to display by pressing that button it should display no. of rows for ex: 5 rows. it is different for every section.each functionality should be done by TableView Only so how it's possible?Please guide me on solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
[yourTableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionNumber];
```

This method checks for number of rows in desired section.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
 int rowsInSection = [tableView.dataSource tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]);
```

That should do the trick.